# I am trying to install pip for Python 3.4, it says "invalid syntax" to install command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to install pip for Python 3.4, it says "invalid syntax" to install command?

Here is the command list:

```
>>> pip install
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/packages/simple/
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> pip install kivy
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> import kivy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    import kivy
ImportError: No module named 'kivy'
```

Comment: Please check your question formatting before posting. You may create a code block by selecting text and clicking the `{}` button. Please [edit] to fix

Comment: You should run pip in your terminal, not in the Python interpreter

Comment: For the next time you should definitely read the [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation.html). In windows and mac parts there are commands written properly so that you could copy&paste for your console/terminal and it'd install. Did you by any change try to install it through `idle` console or something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 2):

Since the prompt looks like `>>>`, it seems you are running it in the python shell or interpreter. That is not how `pip` is supposed to be run. It is installed on the system path, so it is a command that the terminal can execute. Syntax looks like this:

For Linux:

```
pip install [packages]
```

For windows:

```
python -m pip install [packages]
```

Run these in your system terminal, and it should work (as long as my syntax is correct).